# Why Hanuman is not visible to us?

Tags: hanuman, kali-yuga

Hanuman still lives in his material body but why is he not visible? He can do good deeds all over the world and show himself and all of the siddhis he acquired. I do not understand why he will not people see him.

Comment: Previous yugas people are not allowed to come in front of current yugas people. Parshurama, Vibhishan, Ashvatthama, Kripacharya and many more are in material body and still alive but they can't show up in front of us.

Comment: How this question is duplicate of mentioned one? He is not asking where Hanuman is living. Have they even read his question before flagging? lol

Comment: Hanuman is long dead. The concept of chiranjeevi is not meant to be taken literally. It just means long-lived. Not live-forever. You can stop looking for him!

Comment: @sarvabhouma You mentioned Q. is totally different. OP said _"Hanuman still lives in his **material body**"_ He clearly mentioned that he is talking about material body and Gods which being asked in you mentioned Q. is talking about divine body which Gods has before taking birth. Please learn to read full Q. first before commenting :)

Comment: @Rishabh I say the same to you. Read the  complete question. " I do not understand why he will not people see him." It is not known that Hanuman lives with material body. There is no proof of it. The munis and Siddhas living in Himalayas do not have material bodies. If they have, they would be dead and rotten by now. If they are still living, then they are not material bodies. The answer says why we can't see God and the question also asks why we can't see God. It applies to all the Gods. It is problem in the humans not the Gods.

Comment: Did I say Hanuman is dead? Or are you confusing me with sv. ?  I said he doesn't live with material body. He lives with Subtle body. @Rishabh

Comment: @sarvabhouma Do you have any refrence to show that proofs Hanumana changed his body from material to Subtle? And when he did that change? Or it is just your personal opinion.

Comment: @Rishabh When Brahma and other devatas gave boons, it became non-material body. It is not a normal body like us even though there are blood and boons. So, it is not a material and normal body like human beings. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) for clarifications from me and use comments _only for clarifications from author_. I am out of here.

Comment: Hanuman is living atop Mt. Mahendragiri continuously engaged in Ram Nam. Because Rama granted Him a boon that He would be required by Bhaktas in Kali Yuga. So after this Kalpa (possibly chaturyuga) He will not stay in Bhurloka anymore.

Comment: Few people claim that Hanuman was visible to Tulsidas -
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulsidas#Darshan_of_Hanuman